# Set asp:Content programmatically

Tags: asp.net

I'm using a asp.net web application project, and I cannot access any asp:content controls programmaticly. I'm trying to update its contentplaceholderID in code behind. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to change the content of the place holder or change the id of the placeholder?

Comment: im trying to set the value of the contentplaceholderID property on the content control from a web.config appsetting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** you can't change the contentPlaceHolderId in your content page. The reason is that contentplaceholder are set in Master page and then you reference them in there to say in which contentplaceholder your content will go.

> The Content controls get left behind and don’t exist in the control hierarchy. This [ASP.net thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/1140496/1833451.aspx) here gives a way of how you can update it another way though

Comment: What are you actually trying to do because to call a web control in asp.net for any control it is the same

Comment: im trying to set the value of the contentplaceholderID property on the content control from a web.config appsetting.

Comment: @Shawn-just updated answer, didn't know that the contentplaceholder was different

Answer (score 2):

Although you probably cannot change ContentPlaceHolderId of your asp:Contents, you can control the content of ContentPlaceHolders directly: access the master page from the page through its Master property and then use the FindControl function to find the ContentPlaceHolder on the master page. After that, edit its content through the Controls property.

```
var masterContent = Master.FindControl("largeContent") as ContentPlaceHolder;
masterContent.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "Hello, world!" });
```

You could probably use this 'hack' to add an asp:Panel control to any ContentPlaceHolder you want so this might emulate the functionality you wanted.